# Inno Setup: Delete empty lines from test file

Tags: inno-setup

We are using below code to delete empty lines from text file, But it's not working.

```
function UpdatePatchLogFileEntries : Boolean;
var
a_strTextfile : TArrayOfString;
iLineCounter : Integer;
    ConfFile : String;

begin

ConfFile := ExpandConstant('{sd}\patch.log');
    LoadStringsFromFile(ConfFile, a_strTextfile);

    for iLineCounter := 0 to GetArrayLength(a_strTextfile)-1 do
    begin
         if (Pos('', a_strTextfile[iLineCounter]) > 0) then 
            Delete(a_strTextfile[iLineCounter],1,1);
    end;
     SaveStringsToFile(ConfFile, a_strTextfile, False);              
end;
```

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because re-indexing of an array would be inefficient and having two arrays for copying non empty lines of a file would be unecessarily complicated, I would suggest you to use [`TStringList`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStringList) class. It has all what you need wrapped inside. In code I would write function like this:

```
[Code]
procedure DeleteEmptyLines(const FileName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Lines: TStringList;
begin
  // create an instance of a string list
  Lines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // load a file specified by the input parameter
    Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    // iterate line by line from bottom to top (because of reindexing)
    for I := Lines.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      // check if the currently iterated line is empty (after trimming
      // the text) and if so, delete it
      if Trim(Lines[I]) = '' then
        Lines.Delete(I);
    end;
    // save the cleaned-up string list back to the file
    Lines.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    // free the string list object instance
    Lines.Free;
  end;
end;
```